# Python Scrapy: What is the difference between "runspider" and "crawl" commands?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Can someone explain the difference between *runspider* and *crawl* commands? What are the contexts in which they should be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the command:

```
scrapy crawl [options] <spider>
```

`<spider>` is the project name (defined in settings.py, as `BOT_NAME`).

And in the command:

```
scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>
```

`<spider_file>` is the path to the file that contains the spider.

Otherwise, the options are the same:

```
Options
=======
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE           set spider argument (may be repeated)
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items with -o

Global Options
--------------
--logfile=FILE          log file. if omitted stderr will be used
--loglevel=LEVEL, -L LEVEL
                        log level (default: DEBUG)
--nolog                 disable logging completely
--profile=FILE          write python cProfile stats to FILE
--lsprof=FILE           write lsprof profiling stats to FILE
--pidfile=FILE          write process ID to FILE
--set=NAME=VALUE, -s NAME=VALUE
                        set/override setting (may be repeated)
--pdb                   enable pdb on failure
```

Since `runspider` doesn't depend on the `BOT_NAME` parameter, depending on the way you are customising your scrapers, you might find `runspider` more flexible.

Answer (score 11):

The main difference is that `runspider` does not need a project. That is, you can write a spider in a `myspider.py` file and call `scrapy runspider myspider.py`.

The `crawl` command requires a project in order to find the project's settings, load available spiders from `SPIDER_MODULES` settings, and lookup the spider by `name`.

If you need quick spider for a short task, then `runspider` has less boilerplate required.

Comment: how does runpider take its settings then?

Comment: @hAcKnRoCk it's optional. If you use the command `runspider` inside a project directory it will use the project's settings. Otherwise, it will run with the defaults.

Answer (score 9):

The little explanation and syntax of both:

**runspider**

Syntax: `scrapy runspider <spider_file.py>`

Requires project: no

Run a spider self-contained in a Python file, without having to create a project.

**Example usage:**

```
$ scrapy runspider myspider.py
```

**crawl**

Syntax: `scrapy crawl <spider>`

Requires project: yes

Start crawling using a spider with the corresponding name.

**Usage examples:**

```
 $ scrapy crawl myspider
```