# Hello, I am kind of new to scrapy, and I am try to scrape a particular site using scrapy but my scrapy program isn't returning anything

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have looked around for similar problems but I haven't found anything that really addresses the problem.
Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

 import csv

 class quotes(scrapy.Spider):

name='goodreads_quotes'
def get_response(self):
    site='https://www.goodreads.com/{}'
    start_urls=[site.format('quotes')]
    for number in range(1,11):
        start_urls.append(site.format(str(number)))
    yield [scrapy.requests(url=url, callback=self.get_quotes) for url in start_urls]
def get_quotes(self,response):
    quotes=response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract()
    for quote in quotes:
        print('-'*20)
        print(quote)
        csvfile=open('quote.csv','w+')
        csvfile.write(quote)
    csvfile.close()
```

I have crosschecked my css selector
using:

```
 fetch("https://www.goodreads.com/quotes")
 response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract_first()
```

in the scrapy terminal and it seems okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scrapy

class quotes(scrapy.Spider):
    name='goodreads_quotes'
    # Makes primary request with default callback=self.parse
    start_urls = ['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes']

def parse(self,response):
    quotes = response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract()
    for quote in quotes:
        # Scrapy generates result using Item instances. 
        # In simple cases it could be just simple dicts.
        item = {'quote': quote.strip()}
        yield item
```

Run this spider using `scrapy crawl goodreads_quotes -o quotes.csv`
Scrapy automatically handles exporting items in multiple formats, like csv, json, jsonlines. You don't need to write it manually, which will be painful anyway because if async Scrapy nature.

Comment: I tried to run the code using that command but I keep getting [KeyError: 'Spider not found], I am running the code from the right directory and I am also using the right file name so I do not think the problem is from that area.

Comment: oh... my bad, forgot to mention that it works only for project, not for single spider.

Comment: In case of single file spider use `scrapy runspider filename.py`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607390/python-scrapy-what-is-the-difference-between-runspider-and-crawl-commands here's more details.

Comment: Amazing!!!, it worked!!, I have been trying this for sometime now, though there are still some minor problems but I'll figure those out myself. THANKS!

Comment: Glad that I've helped. Good luck! (: